# Clickable Email Address in Guidewire

Tags: guidewire, gosu

Is there a way to make an email address clickable that opens default email client. I am testing this on my local and it works fine. But when I promote code to server it does not work.

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().mail(new java.net.URI("mailTo:"+ user.Contact.EmailAddress1))
```

I'm assuming that java.getDesktop is not available on server side? Is there another way to do this in Guidewire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the email address in a TextInput control, just pick the formatType `email` from the control properties.

If the control would be in read-only state it will display appropriate link starting from `mailto:`